# Density function of max of three samples of an uniform variable $(0, \theta)$

Tags: probability

We have a random variable $X$ with uniform distribution $(0, \theta)$, $\theta > 0$. We have three samples $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$. We want to estimate $\theta$ using $T=\max (X_1, X_2, X_3)$.

What is $P(T<t)$? What's $E\{T\}$?

...

My reasoning so far is that $P(T<t) = P(max(X_1, X_2, X_3)<t) = P(X_1<t) \cap P(X_2<t) \cap P(X_3<t)$.

Now, $P(X_1<t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} f(x) dx$ where $f$ is the density function of the uniform variable $(0, \theta)$, which is $f(x) = 1/\theta$ if $0<x<\theta$.

Now, that depends on whether $t$ is greater or lower than $\theta$, which is not (to my surprise) specified in the problem.

If $t<\theta$ then $P(X_1<t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} 1/\theta dt$ which is $\int_{0}^{t} 1/\theta dt$ which is $t/\theta$.

However if $t>\theta$, $P(X_1<t) = 1$, as $t$ is greater than the greatest value $X$ can be.

Thus:

$$P(T<t) = \begin{cases} (t/\theta)^3 & \text{if $t < \theta$} \\ 1 & \text{if $t > \theta$} \end{cases}$$

Now, $E\{T\} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} t f_T(t) dt$. $f_T(t)$ is the derivative of $F_T(t)$ which is $P(T<t)$, thus:

$$f_T(t) = \begin{cases} (3t^2/\theta^3) & \text{if $t < \theta$} \\ 0 & \text{if $t > \theta$} \end{cases}$$

but here I am stuck as I'm unsure about how to calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}} t f_T(t) dt$

Help? Is my reasoning up to this point correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are mostly correct.  To be more precise, $$\Pr[T < t] = \begin{cases} 0, & t < 0 \\ (t/\theta)^3, & 0 \le t \le \theta, \\ 1 & \theta < t. \end{cases}$$  Then the density is given by $$f_T(t) = \begin{cases} 3t^2/\theta^3, & 0 < t \le \theta, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$  The expectation is simply $$\operatorname{E}[T] = \int_{t=0}^\theta t f_T(t) \, dt = \frac{3}{\theta^3} \int_{t=0}^\theta t^3 \, dt = \frac{3}{\theta^3} \left[\frac{t^4}{4} \right]_{t=0}^\theta = \frac{3}{\theta^3} \left(\frac{\theta^4}{4} - 0 \right) = \frac{3\theta}{4}.$$